# Include keyword no longer working in .Net Core Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a loan application model as follows:

```
public class LoanApplication
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [DefaultSortable]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid Identifier { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public string GlobalEmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string ResidentialAddress { get; set; }
    

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

It is linked to an employee class which already exists in the database:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [DefaultSortable]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Sortable]
    public int? OrganizationId { get; set; }

    [Searchable, Sortable]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Searchable, Sortable]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Searchable, Sortable]
    public string OtherNames { get; set; }

    [Searchable, Sortable]
    [Required]
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [Searchable, Sortable]
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

    [Sortable]
    public string DepartmentId { get; set; }

    [Sortable]
    public string JobPositionId { get; set; }

    [Sortable]
    public string DivisionId { get; set; }

    [Sortable]
    public string UnitId { get; set; }

    [Sortable]
    public string PayBandId { get; set; }

    [Sortable]
    public string OrganisationLocationId { get; set; }

    [Sortable]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public EmployeePosition Position { get; set; }

    [Sortable]
    public bool Resident { get; set; } = true;

    [Sortable]
    public bool HasSecondaryEmployment { get; set; }

    [Searchable, Sortable]
    public string TIN { get; set; }
     
    [Searchable, Sortable]
    public string SocialSecurityNumber { get; set; }

    public string NationalIdType { get; set; }

    [Searchable, Sortable]
    public string NationalIdNumber { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrganizationId")]
    [IgnoreInJsonBackup]
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PayScheduleId")]
    [IgnoreInJsonBackup]
    public PaySchedule PaySchedule { get; set; }

    
}
```

I noticed that on creating a new loan application, the loan application object does have the employee object attached as expected. Example response of a call to an endpoint to create the loan application, which returns the newly-created loan application:

```
{
    "id": 5,
  "identifier": "e4cc7864-c18a-4e75-a7a1-8ab54e9a7fdc",
  "organizationId": "1dd71d10-fac7-4f33-87df-679a9541bba1",
  "globalEmployeeId": "a8185c5b-50ca-4bcf-a8a5-dd74b0c1ab6b-20191029141650",
  "name": "Amal",
  "birthDate": "1993-02-07T00:00:00",
  "email": "email@email.com",
  "phoneNumber": "818927999",
  "residentialAddress": "nowhere",
  "loanAmount": 300,
  "purposeOfLoan": "to live",
  "tenureUnit": "Month",
  "tenureDuration": 6,
  "employeeId": 139,
  "employee": {
    "id": 139,
    "organizationId": 1,
    "firstName": "Aladdin",
    "lastName": "Acosta",
    "otherNames": "Amal",
    "gender": null,
    "employeeId": "a8185c5b-50ca-4bcf-a8a5-dd74b0c1ab6b-20191029141650",
    "employeeNumber": "EMP-0274",
    "departmentId": "bee9a1a9-2c46-4611-ad78-55c55cbfb671",
    "jobPositionId": "ebf362dc-0a73-48a7-b31b-d64bca31550c",
    "divisionId": null,
    "unitId": null,
    "payBandId": null,
    "organization": {
      "id": 1,
      "organizationId": "1dd71d10-fac7-4f33-87df-679a9541bba1",
      "name": "Fair Cat",
      "emailAddress": "fair@cat.com",
      "country": "GH",
      "state": null,
      
    },
    "paySchedule": null
  }
}
```

But on subsequently obtaining it from the database, the employee object is always absent, even if I use Include as in the following example query:

```
var loanApplication = context.LoanApplications.Include(x => x.Employee).
            FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrganizationId == organizationId &&
                    x.Identifier.ToString() == identifier);
```

Example of response when getting a loan application from a GET endpoint. Notice that the employee field is now null:

```
{


"id": 5,
  "identifier": "e4cc7864-c18a-4e75-a7a1-8ab54e9a7fdc",
  "organizationId": "1dd71d10-fac7-4f33-87df-679a9541bba1",
  "globalEmployeeId": "a8185c5b-50ca-4bcf-a8a5-dd74b0c1ab6b-20191029141650",
  "name": "Amal",
  "birthDate": "1993-02-07T00:00:00",
  "email": "email@email.com",
  "phoneNumber": "818927999",
  "residentialAddress": "nowhere",
  "loanAmount": 300,
  "purposeOfLoan": "to live",
  "tenureUnit": "Month",
  "tenureDuration": 6,
  "employeeId": 139,
  "employee": null
}
```

ETA: Other existing models I have with similarly-linked navigation properties also have these navigation properties null when they previously used to work fine, but I have not made any change in that regard.

ETA: Db context class added as requested

```
public class AppDataContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDataContext(DbContextOptions<AppDataContext> options)
       : base(options)
    {
        this.Database.SetCommandTimeout(180);
        Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": DB Context created on thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<OrganizationBankAccount> OrganizationBankAccounts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PayItem> PayItems { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PayStructure> PayStructures { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PayRun> PayRuns { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PayRunTask> PayRunTasks { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PayPeriod> PayPeriods { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EmployeePayRun> EmployeePayRuns { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ArchivedEmployeePayRun> ArchivedEmployeePayRuns { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PaySchedule> PaySchedules { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PayrollNotification> PayrollNotifications { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<List> Lists { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<OrganizationLocation> OrganizationLocations { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EmployeeHire> EmployeeHires { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EmployeeTermination> EmployeeTerminations { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<InitialPayRun> InitialPayRuns { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<RemittanceParty> RemittanceParties { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EmployeePayChange> EmployeePayChanges { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<MappingStructure> MappingStructures { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AccountMappingState> AccountMappingStates { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ContractorType> ContractorTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PayRunAccountingPostingRecord> PayRunAccountingPostingRecords { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Jurisdiction> Jurisdictions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<JurisdictionScript> JurisdictionScripts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TaxReliefType> TaxReliefTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PayrollOnboarding> PayrollOnboardings { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PayItemTemplate> PayItemTemplates { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<FixedPayItem> FixedPayItems { get; set; }      
    public virtual DbSet<PayrollEvent> Events { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<JurisdictionDefault> JurisdictionDefaults { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PayrollToken> Tokens { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<JobGrade> JobGrades { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PayGroup> PayGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ApprovalScheme> ApprovalSchemes { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<PayRunData> PayRunData { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DataUpdate> DataUpdates { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EmployeePayHistoryItem> EmployeePayHistory { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Holiday> Holidays{ get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<PaymentBatch> PaymentBatches { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PaymentRecord> PaymentRecords { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<EmployeeSubscription> EmployeeSubscriptions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SubscriptionEnrolment> SubscriptionEnrolments { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<LoanApplication> LoanApplications { get; set; }


    public virtual DbSet<BaseEmployeePayRun> BaseEmployeePayRuns { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PayRevision> PayRevisions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SubscriptionProfile> SubscriptionProfiles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PayRunSubscriptionAllocation> PayRunSubscriptionAllocations { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PaymentRecordSubscriptionAllocation> PaymentSubscriptionAllocations { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PayRunAllocatedPayment> PayRunPaymentAllocations { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PaymentRecordAllocatedPayment> PaymentRecordPaymentAllocations { get; set; }

    //public virtual DbSet<XeroToken> XeroTokens { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>().HasIndex(organization => organization.JurisdictionId).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>().Property(organization => organization.PayslipPasswordMethod)
            .HasConversion(
                v => v.ToString(),
                v => (PayslipPasswordMethod) Enum.Parse(typeof(PayslipPasswordMethod), v)
            );
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasIndex(employee => employee.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PayItem>().HasIndex(payItem => payItem.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PaySchedule>().HasIndex(paySchedule => paySchedule.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PayStructure>().HasIndex(payStructure => payStructure.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PayStructure>().HasIndex(payStructure =>payStructure.Scope).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PayStructure>().HasIndex(payStructure => payStructure.OwnerId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PayRun>().HasIndex(payRun => payRun.PayScheduleId).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PayRun>().HasIndex(payRun => payRun.DateCreated).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PayRun>().HasIndex(payRun => payRun.Status).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PayRun>().HasIndex(payRun => payRun.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PayRun>().HasIndex(payRun => payRun.DatePosted).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PayPeriod>().HasIndex(payPeriod => payPeriod.PayScheduleId).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PayPeriod>().HasIndex(payPeriod => payPeriod.PayRunPosted).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeePayRun>().HasIndex(employeePayRun => employeePayRun.PayRunId).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeePayRun>().HasIndex(employeePayRun => employeePayRun.DateGenerated).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeePayRun>().HasIndex(employeePayRun => employeePayRun.EmployeeId).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeePayRun>().HasIndex(employeePayRun => employeePayRun.Excluded).IsUnique(false);


        modelBuilder.Entity<ArchivedEmployeePayRun>().HasIndex(archivedEmployeePayRun => archivedEmployeePayRun.PayRunId).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ArchivedEmployeePayRun>().HasIndex(archivedEmployeePayRun => archivedEmployeePayRun.DateGenerated).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ArchivedEmployeePayRun>().HasIndex(archivedEmployeePayRun => archivedEmployeePayRun.DateArchived).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ArchivedEmployeePayRun>().HasIndex(archivedEmployeePayRun => archivedEmployeePayRun.EmployeeId).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ArchivedEmployeePayRun>().HasIndex(archivedEmployeePayRun => archivedEmployeePayRun.Excluded).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PayRunTask>().HasIndex(payRunTask => payRunTask.PayRunId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<List>().HasIndex(list => list.OrganisationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrganizationBankAccount>().HasIndex(organizationBankAccount => organizationBankAccount.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PayrollNotification>().HasIndex(pn => pn.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<FixedPayItem>().HasIndex(fixedPayItem => fixedPayItem.JurisdictionId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PayItemTemplate>().HasIndex(pit => pit.JurisdictionId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TaxReliefType>().HasIndex(tr => tr.JurisdictionId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PayrollEvent>().HasIndex(tr => tr.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeHire>().HasIndex(eh => eh.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeHire>().HasIndex(eh => eh.EmployeeId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeTermination>().HasIndex(et => et.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeTermination>().HasIndex(et => et.EmployeeId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<InitialPayRun>().HasIndex(i => i.PayRunId).IsUnique(true);

        modelBuilder.Entity<RemittanceParty>().HasIndex(r => r.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<JurisdictionScript>().HasIndex(js => js.JurisdictionId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeePayChange>().HasIndex(r => r.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<JurisdictionDefault>().HasIndex(jd => jd.JurisdictionId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasIndex(acc => acc.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MappingStructure>().HasIndex(ms => ms.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AccountMappingState>().HasIndex(ams => ams.PayRunId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ContractorType>().HasIndex(ct => ct.JurisdictionId).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ContractorType>().HasIndex(ct => ct.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PayRunAccountingPostingRecord>().HasIndex(pr => pr.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PayItem>().HasIndex(payItem => new { payItem.Code, payItem.OrganizationId }).IsUnique(true);

        modelBuilder.Entity<JobGrade>().HasIndex(j => j.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PayGroup>().HasIndex(pg => pg.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApprovalScheme>().HasIndex(pg => pg.OrganizationId).IsUnique(true);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PayRunData>().HasIndex(payRun => payRun.PayRunId).IsUnique(true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PayRunData>().HasIndex(payRun => payRun.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<DataUpdate>().HasIndex(t => t.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeePayHistoryItem>().HasIndex(x => x.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeePayHistoryItem>().HasIndex(x => x.EmployeeId).IsUnique(false);


        modelBuilder.Entity<Holiday>().HasIndex(e => e.Country).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentBatch>().HasIndex(x => x.PayRunId).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentBatch>().HasIndex(x => x.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentRecord>().HasIndex(x => x.EmployeePayRunId).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentRecord>().HasIndex(x => x.PaymentBatchId).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentRecord>().HasIndex(x => x.PayRunIdentifier).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeSubscription>().HasIndex(x => x.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeSubscription>().HasIndex(x => x.SubscriptionIdentifier).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<LoanApplication>().HasIndex(x => x.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SubscriptionEnrolment>().HasIndex(x => x.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<BaseEmployeePayRun>(bepr =>
            {
                bepr.HasNoKey();
                bepr.ToView("BaseEmployeePayRuns");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PayRevision>(pr =>
        {
            pr.HasNoKey();
            pr.ToView("PayRevisions");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<SubscriptionProfile>(pr =>
        {
            pr.HasNoKey();
            pr.ToView("SubscriptionProfiles");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PayRunSubscriptionAllocation>(spa =>
        {
            spa.HasNoKey();
            spa.ToView("PayRunSubscriptionAllocations");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentRecordSubscriptionAllocation>(spa =>
        {
            spa.HasNoKey();
            spa.ToView("PaymentSubscriptionAllocations");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PayRunAllocatedPayment>(spa =>
        {
            spa.HasNoKey();
            spa.ToView("PayRunPaymentAllocations");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentRecordAllocatedPayment>(spa =>
        {
            spa.HasNoKey();
            spa.ToView("PaymentRecordPaymentAllocations");
        });

    }
}
```

ETA: Generated query:

```
SELECT l."Id", l."ApprovedByIdentifier", l."ApprovedByName", l."BankAccountName", l."BankAccountNumber", l."BankName", l."BirthDate", l."CancelledByIdentifier", l."CancelledByName", l."DateApproved", l."DateCancelled", l."DateCreated", l."DateDeclined", l."DateUpdated", l."DeclinedByIdentifier", l."DeclinedByName", l."Email", l."EmployeeId", l."GHCardNumber", l."GHCard_Back", l."GHCard_Front", l."GlobalEmployeeId", l."Identifier", l."LoanAgreementForm", l."LoanAmount", l."Name", l."OrganizationId", l."PassportPicture", l."Payslip1", l."Payslip2", l."PhoneNumber", l."PurposeOfLoan", l."ResidentialAddress", l."Status", l."TenureDuration", l."TenureUnit", l.loan_application_comments
FROM "LoanApplications" AS l
WHERE (l."OrganizationId" = @__organizationId_0) AND (CAST(l."Identifier" AS text) = @__identifier_1)
LIMIT 1
```

- *(note that extra fields in this query, such as ApprovedByIdentifier, etc) do not appear in the class object above because I simply cut them out so that the code snippet would not be too long)*

Comment: Can you add the code from your DbContext class in order to show how the entities are configured?

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong. Check if the generated query has a join.

Comment: @GertArnold I checked and the generated query (now added to the question) does not have a Join.

Answer (score 0):

When I asked for your to provide the DbContext class, I suspected that the relationship was not fully configured. Now, I'm not entirely certain that this is what is causing the issue but I think it would be worth a try.

In your `DbContext` class, fully configure the relationship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LoanApplication>(entity =>
{               
    entity.HasOne(d => d.Employee)
        .WithMany(p => p.LoanApplications)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.EmployeeId)
        .HasIndex(x => x.OrganizationId).IsUnique(false);
});
```

In `LoanApplication`:

```
[ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
[InverseProperty("LoanApplications")]
public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
```

In `Employee`:

```
public Employee()
{        
    LoanApplications = new HashSet<LoanApplication>();        
}

[InverseProperty("Employee")]
public virtual ICollection<LoanApplication> LoanApplications { get; set; }
```

I may have misunderstood the relationship so I would double check to make sure the relationship is accurate. But with that said, once you have your relationship configured correctly I suspect this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. Though I already tried the first part (modelBulilder...), to no effect- this line already seems to exist in the context model snapshot class anyways. I could try the rest as well, but I would be still puzzled as to why other classes I have (Employee, Organization) did not require the hash-set and InverseProperty tag additions for the foreign key relationship to work as expected...

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get it to work although I have no clue why.
I used to access all my data via repository classes, rather than accessing the context directly.
Just to tryout if this could be the issue, I implemented a repo class for the loan applications:

```
public class LoanApplicationRepository : Repository<LoanApplication>, ILoanApplicationRepository
{
    public LoanApplicationRepository(AppDataContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override string GetTableName()
    {
        return nameof(context.LoanApplications);
    }

    #region Get functions


    public override IQueryable<LoanApplication> Get(Expression<Func<LoanApplication, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return context.Set<LoanApplication>().Where(predicate).AsQueryable().Include(x => x.Employee);
    }

    #endregion

}
```

It is based on this base class (only a few GET functions, but the others are mostly just variations of CRUD):

```
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly AppDataContext context;

    
    

    #region Get functions
    public virtual T Find(int id)
    {
        return context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }

    public virtual T Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var result= context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToList();
        return result.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetUntracked(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
    }

    public virtual List<T> GetAllList()
    {
        return context.Set<T>().ToList();
    }

    public virtual List<T> GetList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToList();
    }

    public virtual async Task<List<T>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return await context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
    }

    public virtual async Task<List<T>> GetUntrackedAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return await context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
    }

    public virtual async Task<T> FindAsync(int id)
    {
        return await context.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
    }

    public int GetCount(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        int count = context.Set<T>().Count(predicate);
        return count;
    }


    public virtual async Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public virtual List<T> GetWithRawConditions(List<NpgsqlParameter> parameters, List<string> conditions)
    {
        var selectStatement = getSelectClause() + " WHERE " + string.Join(" AND ", conditions);

        var result = context.Set<T>().
            FromSqlRaw(selectStatement, parameters.ToArray()).
            AsNoTracking().
            ToList();

        return result;
    }

    public virtual async Task<List<T>> GetWithRawConditionsAsync(List<NpgsqlParameter> parameters, List<string> conditions)
    {
        var selectStatement = getSelectClause() + " WHERE " + string.Join(" AND ", conditions);

        var result = await context.Set<T>().
            FromSqlRaw(selectStatement, parameters.ToArray()).
            AsNoTracking().
            ToListAsync();

        return result;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Now I am able to get the loan application object with the employee attached, and the generated query now includes a join.
I wish I could figure out why though.